# Selenium grid hub behind nginx proxy

Tags: selenium, nginx, selenium-grid

Can you run a Selenium server hub behind nginx, to proxy port 443/ssl (or 80 without) to localhost:4444 where Selenium server is bound? My remote nodes won't connect to Selenium server behind nginx, only if I specifically open port 4444 in the firewall and bypass nginx do remote nodes connect.

Comment: Can you not just use the port command line parameter to bind selenium grid to port 80?

Comment: I am trying to set it up behind a secured HAproxy. I'm redirecting any 80 to 443, and I mapped 443 to 4444. I believe the issue I'm having is with a self signed certificate. Without SSL, port redirection works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if nginx handles this. I imagine the problem is more that your network firewall blocks ports outside 443 and certain others, and expects all traffic to go via HTTPS.

1. Get your network administrators to allow a punch-through for port 443.
2. Host your CI platform behind the firewalled network
3. Look for an alternate way to access the application nodes -- some firewalled networks allow access to public nodes from a private network via a different IP/hostname from the normal ones

I don't think you could really run Selenium on, say, port 80, because the selenium server itself is not quite really a web service.

Comment: Why not run it on port 80? Unless something else is already bound to port 80 why would it matter? A port is a port is a port. As it happens I use nginx with multiple appium instances behind it - I didn't bother with Selenium Grid - I use nginx as the router to each instance.

Comment: @daveL I suppose you could, but 443 is the standard HTTPS port. 80 is for non-secure HTTP. Of course, you could do "http**s**://websitename:80" and that *should* work.

Comment: I do not see where the OP suggested a requirement for encrypted HTTP. Maybe I missed it. And I'm yet to see anywhere that required secure comms for test tools which are usually in the main hosted in intranet test environments. OP - do you need secure HTTP?

Answer (score -2):

it's maybe a bit late for answering the question of @xref. However, I have just deployed my Selenium Grid behind Nginx.

In order to do so, I used Docker and Docker-Compose. I describe how to do it [here](https://gist.github.com/jackTheRipper/db13c68c2ec78e50d03ac55f06da9726)

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Links can easily stop functioning no matter how careful the user is. Therefore it's safer to copy the essential parts on SO. Could you be so kind to do that? Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: Like you said the link is not valid... @JackTheRipper could you provide if it still exists?